# Split strings on whitespaces and count individual occurrences in R

Tags: r, dplyr, split, count, tidyverse

I'm looking for a solution to a question that seems to be simple. I want all strings in the column `var1` to be split on whitespaces and then counted. Ideally, the rows containing `NA` and string called `error` should be not included in the count as well as instances wrapped in square brackets, e.g., `[ZZ]`.

If anyone has a suggestion on how to go about it, I would really appreciate it.

**Dummy example**

```
d1 <- data.frame(var1 = c('AAA AA AA BB CC', 'BB [ZZ]', 'NA','error','[ZZ] DD' ))
```

**Dummy table**

```
#              var1
# 1 AAA AA AA BB CC
# 2         BB [ZZ]
# 3              NA
# 4           error
# 5         [ZZ] DD
```

**Desired output**

```
  var1 count
1  AAA     1
2   AA     2
3   BB     2
4   CC     1
5 DDDD     1
```

Comment: where did you get `DDDD` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhhaps something like this:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

d1<-data.frame(var1 = c('AAA AA AA BB CC', 'BB [ZZ]', 'NA','error','[ZZ] DD' ))

d1 %>% separate_longer_delim(var1, regex("\\s+")) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(var1, regex("^(na|error|\\[.*\\])$", ignore_case = TRUE), negate = TRUE)) %>% 
  count(var1)
#>   var1 n
#> 1   AA 2
#> 2  AAA 1
#> 3   BB 2
#> 4   CC 1
#> 5   DD 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A `base` solution:

```r
table(scan(text = gsub("\\[.+\\]|error|NA", "", d1$var1), what = ''))

# AA AAA  BB  CC  DD 
#  2   1   2   1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using `grepl` in `filter` and `count` to get the occurrences

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(var1 = unlist(strsplit(d1$var1, " "))) %>% 
  filter(!grepl("^\\[|(NA)|[a-z]", vec)) %>% 
  count(var1, name="count")
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  var1  count
  <chr> <int>
1 AA        2
2 AAA       1
3 BB        2
4 CC        1
5 DD        1
```